# Using a function as the parameter for another function in PHP

Tags: php, function, parameters

This may be strange and probably doesn't work but I wanted to check before I gave up on the idea. Essentially, I'm trying to use the results of a function as one of the parameters for another function. For example - function1($param1, function2($param1));.

The code I've included outputs everything I want it to, the only issue I'm having is that it outputs it in the wrong order - rather than outputting: logos, h2, form, h2, form; it outputs: form, h2, logos, form, h2.

```
// Display list
function ul($c, $p){
        echo '<ul class="'.$c.'">'.$p.'</ul>';
    }
    // Display list item
    function li($c, $p){
        echo '<li class="'.$c.'">'.$p.'</li>';
    }    
// Display navigation
        function nav(){
            require 'strings.php';
            // If the user is not logged in, display the login form
            if(!isset($_SESSION[$uss])){
                $nav = li('', require_once 'log_in.php');
            // Otherwise provide the user information and navigation
            }else{
                $nav = li($lks, $_SESSION[$uss][$uns]).
                       li($dss, $uss.' Id: '.$_SESSION[$uss]['id']).
                       li($dss, $uss.' Type: '.$_SESSION[$uss]['type']).
                       '<div id="display_projects_container">'.
                       require_once('display_projects.php').
                       '</div>'.
                       li($lks, '<a href="newsfeed.php" class="'.$lks.'">News Feed</a>').
                       li($dss, 'Check for updates.').
                       li($lks, '<a href="task_list.php" class="'.$lks.'">Task List</a>').
                       li($dss, 'Tasks to be completed.').
                       li($lks, '<a href="logout.php" class="'.$lks.'">Log Out</a>').
                       li($dss, 'Time for a burrito!');
            }
            echo '<div id="left_column">
                <!--After Breakpoint Logo-->
                <img src="logo.png" class="after_breakpoint_logo" />';
                ul('navigation', '<!--Before Breakpoint Logo-->'.
                                 li('before_breakpoint_logo', '<a href="index.php">
       <img src="logo.png" class="before_breakpoint_logo" /></a>').
                                 $nav);
                echo '</div><div id="content_container"><div id="content">';
        }
```

Is there a work around for this? Or is it just not possible to do?

Comment: Without seeing what `li` and `ul` do I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: I've added the li and ul functions to the code now. I'm assuming the issue is with the fact that the functions echo out their results. I'm just not sure what to do instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are echoing your results to the output. Instead you should use your `li` and `ul` functions to build up and `return` a string that the caller will then echo out or do as it pleases. Therefore your `ul`and `li` functions should become:

```
function ul($c, $p){
    return '<ul class="'.$c.'">'.$p.'</ul>';
}

function li($c, $p){
    return '<li class="'.$c.'">'.$p.'</li>';
}
```

You would then call `li` many times as you are doing to set `$nav`. Then to put it all together, in the final call you would have:

```
echo ul('navigation', '<!--Before Breakpoint Logo-->'. 
    li('before_breakpoint_logo', '<a href="index.php">
       <img src="logo.png" class="before_breakpoint_logo" /></a>'). $nav);
```